# made live usb but macos won't detect it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, mac

So I fully installed ubuntu on a 64 Gb USB from an install drive, so it acts as a full hard drive. I booted it on my OLD pc and it worked fine but when I restarted my mac and held option with the USB plugged in it didn't show up as an option to boot from. only showing macintosh HD. How do I force the mac to boot from this?